# How to set up a disk-image

Tags: disk-image

I created an Android Open Source project that requires to be installed on an Ubuntu machine a lot of tools, packages. In order to facilitate contributions, I want to create a disk-image with all pre-installed tools and configurations. Is there a simple way to do that? Do I need docker?

Answer (score 3):

You could package it as **ISO** archive (or any other archive like **tar**, **zip**, ...) using the **Archive Manager** from Nautilus' context menu of a file or folder:

Open your **Files Manager** (Nautilus) and navigate to the location of what you want to package. Right-click on that and select **Compress...** from the context menu. The window below will appear:

[image]

Enter a **filename** select a **format/suffix** from the drop-down list on the right. I selected **.iso** here. On some formats you can set a password or split the archive up into smaller chunks, but **ISO** does not support any of those **Other Options**. Then chose a target directory where to place the created archive and click on <kbd>Create</kbd>.

[image]

Once the archive is created, you can either normally open it using the **Archive Manager** (file-roller) or you can mount it like a disk image using **Archive Mounter**.

Therefore navigate to the location of the archive in your **Files Manager** (Nautilus) and right-click on it. In the context menu, select **Open with → Archive Mounter**.

[image]

It will automatically mount the archive anywhere and you can access it through the list of devices in the left part of Nautilus.

The **Archive Mounter** should be able to somehow mount most archive formats.
When you created an **ISO** archive, you also have the additional option to open it with **Disk Image Mounter**. That one does mount it like a real CD/DVD and uses the mount point `/media/<<YOUR_USERNAME>>/CDROM`.